# how close showModalBottomSheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver{

  PersistentBottomSheetController controller;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    requestPermission(Permission.location);
    getIdentifierState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

Future<void> requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    final status = await permission.request();

    if(status != PermissionStatus.granted){
      _showModalBottomSheet(context);
    }else{
      // how close _showModalBottomSheet
      Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      print(position.latitude);
      print(position.longitude);
      bloc.coordinate(position.latitude.toString() + position.longitude.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: use Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close modal bottom sheet programmatically in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778866/close-modal-bottom-sheet-programmatically-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

When calling your method, pass the parameter `context` to be used during modal closing as follow:

> Navigator.of(context).pop();

Answer (score 0):

within the sheet add a button with the following action

```dart
    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },)
```