# Is it possible to enable tap outside the bottomsheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet, gesture-recognition, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to enable users to **take actions outside the bottom sheet** as well. For example in the image shown below, I want the user to make a tap on the **play** button. I cannot do that now since the barrier of the bottomsheet is blocking the click to the play button.

[image]

- From my research, the bottom sheet is a full-screen component. It appears to be of height half screen is a deception. (By making barrier color transparent and adding height constraints).

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isDismissible: false,
      barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: height),
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            child: child.....
          ),
        );
      },
      isScrollControlled: true,
    );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406821/6618622

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Not what they are asking. Suman: you should not use a bottom sheet in this case. You can use a stack where you want the comment section to appear.

Comment: I have that as a backup plan :D

Comment: exactly, its half transparent and half is the widget you provide, if you need to work it out may be like this, put the background and your bottomSheet widget in a stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like bottom sheet but with a different method.
I hope I got the question right.

[image: example gif]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class BottomSheetOutside extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomSheetOutsideState createState() => _BottomSheetOutsideState();
}

class _BottomSheetOutsideState extends State<BottomSheetOutside> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset.zero).animate(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: buildTop),
          Expanded(flex: 6, child: buildBottom),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container get buildTop {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_fill_rounded),
        onPressed: () {
          switch (_controller.status) {
            case AnimationStatus.dismissed:
              _controller.forward();
              break;
            case AnimationStatus.forward:
              break;
            case AnimationStatus.reverse:
              break;
            case AnimationStatus.completed:
              _controller.reverse();
              break;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Stack get buildBottom {
    return Stack(children: [
      Container(color: Colors.blue),
      buildBottomSlide,
    ]);
  }

  Widget get buildBottomSlide {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: offset,
      child: Card(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.comment),
            title: Text("Test $index"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```