# My modalBottomSheet is draggable just on edges

Tags: flutter, listview, draggable, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have a `DraggableScrollableSheet` inside of a `showModalBottomSheet` builder. I have set `isDismissible: true` for modal sheet but my widget is draggable just on edges. That is because I have a `ListView` inside of `DraggableScrollableSheet`.

What I should do for when the list is overscrolled on top the drag to start?

Here goes my code:

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      isDismissible: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      enableDrag: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StackedSheet(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          onBackgroundColor: onBackgroundColor,
          padding: padding,
          minChildSize: minChildSize,
          maxChildSize: maxChildSize,
          onClose: onClose,
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Where **StackedSheet** is:

```
LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return DraggableScrollableSheet(
            key: Key('$_childSize'),
            initialChildSize: min(_childSize, widget.maxChildSize),
            minChildSize:
                min(_childSize - _childSize * 0.2, widget.minChildSize),
            maxChildSize: min(_childSize, widget.maxChildSize),
            expand: false,
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              ScrollController scrollController,
            ) {
              return ListView.separated( ...blah blah)
           }
```

Here is a GIF:

[image: Here is a GIF:]

Instead of bouncing, my desire is to start to be dragged down.

Comment: Can you just paste the code you have written?

Comment: Can you show some type of demonstration with image or GIF because I am not able to understand the exact problem?

Comment: @GautamGoyal i edited the question with the actual behaviour..

Comment: try shrinkWrap=true inside your Listview widget

Comment: now is not bouncing anymore... but still not dragging too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234560/discussion-between-gautam-goyal-and-ovidiu-usvat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can use scroll controller to dismiss bottomsheet on reaching top something like this

```
if (_controller.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent &&
            !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
           .....
           ..... 
         );
       }
```

You can stop list from bouncing at top using `shrinkWrap=true` in Listview.
And to dismiss the bottomsheet you can refer to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778866/close-modal-bottom-sheet-programmatically-in-flutter)

I haven't tried this code but hopefully it will help you in some way.

Also, I think it will look good if you will keep it the way it is now by inserting a little "-" at top on right side of "X" ,on which user can touch to slide down.

Comment: Did it helped you?