# Flutter: How to prevent two bottom sheet showed at a time?

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have a global stream and it's listener. Simply, if something was added to the stream, the app will call `showModalBottomSheet` function. The problem is, sometimes in the process I have to add two value to the stream, but I only want one modal bottom sheet to be shown.

I was looking for how to close current shown bottom sheet in Flutter as we do with the Snackbar by invoking `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackbar()`.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406821/11621203) on how to close a bottom sheet programmatically using PersistentBottomSheetController but I think it doesn't suit in my problem since I use the showModalBottomSheet which is not a part of Scaffold.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a boolean flag to check whether a Bottom Sheet is already opened before invoking showModalBottomSheet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It can be an alternative, but I think there is another way to do it other than having a global boolean flag since this modal bottom sheet need to be controlled globally.